# How to count attribute which have same value in HTML with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code of HTML,

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>content</td>
<td>content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">one</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>content</td>
<td>content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">two</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>content</td>
<td>content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">three</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I really want is to count the "colspan", and take the those contents from those table with JavaScript only, no jquery and mootool please. Thanks you.

I have got the answer for this, can we optimize to be shorter code or just simply the code?

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName( 'td' );
var colspanCount = 0;
var valuecount = 0;
for( i=0; i<tds.length; i++ ) {
    myvalue = (tds[i].hasAttribute( 'colspan' ));
    if (myvalue == true) {
     valuecount += 1;
    }

}
document.write('my value is ' + valuecount);
```

Comment: One question: Why? And I ask this because I _smell_ there is better way of doing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using jQuery would be best, but something like this should work:

```
var tablecols = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i in tablecols) {
    if (tablecols[i].getAttribute('colspan') != undefined) {
        alert(tablecols[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Please note that this is untested.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should probably loop over the tags by doing something like document.getElementsByTagName("td") and then use the getAttribute method on each of those objects and see if it returns you  a value for colspan..

Pseudo code:

```
tds=document.getElementsByTagName("td")
for i fom 0 to tds.length
if tds[i].getAttribute("colspan") is defined
//do smthing
```

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName( 'td' );

var colspanCount = 0;
for( i=0; i<tds.length; i++ ) {
    colspanCount += tds[i].hasAttribute( 'colspan' ) ? parseInt( tds[i].getAttribute( 'colspan' )) : 0;
}

document.write( 'Count: ' + colspanCount );
```

Tested to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/kmfvu/

Comment: it shows the all value adding of attribute value, so the result is like 6 instead of 3. it doesn't count of colspan. can you please have a look. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Myself, I'd just use jQuery.

You can cheap-out and treat it like string and use `.split('colspan="2"')` then the length - 1 will be your answer.